# Two-Points Padé Approximant

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, approximation

My Question is about two points Pade approximant

From Mathematica References. I just find the Pade approximant for a real function in one point

Example :

```
PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {2, 3}}]
```

which is an approximation of the exponential function on $0$

Is there any way to find Padé approximant in two points, for example, if we want to obtain the Padé approximant of  the Exponential function in $0$ and $1$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MultipointPadeApproximants/

Comment: not exactely, I would like to obtain an explicit expression. I already tried this code  but the output gives nothing

Comment: Maybe you can also mention it in the post, so others can see that as well.

Comment: And another quick question: are you aware that the command works for arbitrary parameters? What I mean is that PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, a, {2, 3}}] returns a result and you can sub for a any value you want

Comment: thanks, yes I know, but I would like to obtain a fraction of degree less than 3 for example that gives the exact value in the two points of approximation

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0  "PadeContFraction" seems not foolproof. Try e.g.: `f[x_] = Sinc[2 x];
pts = Transpose@Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/2}];
f1[x_] = PadeContFraction @@ pts`  and you see that PadeContFraction throws 1/0 errors.

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks for that. To be honest, it would have been helpful if the OP had an example worked out by hand, to see what the goal was originally. It was difficult for me to understand the two-point expansion from the ordinary definition. Perhaps this is my lack of experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea how you could proceed:

Let's take your example of f[x_]=Exp[x] and you would like a 2 point approx. at x=0 and x=1. Toward this aim, you could make a Pade approximation at x=0 and x=1 with a numerator degree of m (e.g.2) and denominator degree of n (e.g. 2). This gives you two rational functions, one for x=0 and one for x=1. Now, you could interpolate the coefficients of these function (in this example linear) to get a better approximation. Here is the proceeding:

First we get the Pade approximation and separate numerator and denominator:

```
n = 3; m = 2;
t1 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {n, m}}];
t2 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 1, {n, m}}];
t1 = NumeratorDenominator[t1];
t2 = NumeratorDenominator[t2];
```

Next we get the coefficients of the numerator and denominator polynomials:

```
t1 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t1;
t2 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t2;
```

Now, for the interpolation we need to add the x parts:

```
t1 = Map[{0, #} &, t1, {2}];
t2 = Map[{1, #} &, t2, {2}];
```

Now we are ready for interpolation:

```
t3 = Interpolation[#, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose[{t1[[1]], t2[[1]]}];
t4 = Interpolation[#, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose[{t1[[2]], t2[[2]]}];
```

Finally we get the approximation:

```
approx[x_] = t3.x^Range[0, n]/ t4.x^Range[0, m];
Plot[{approx[x], Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Now it is interesting to compare the error of our approximation to the error of the Pade approximant at x=0:

```
errpad[x_] = Exp[x] - PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {n, m}}];
Plot[{Exp[x] - approx[x], errpad[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

It is obvious that the error at x=0 and x=1 is zero and not bad in between.

**Addendum**

If you do not want to use "Interpolation" you may do the interpolation "by hand":

```
n = 3; m = 2;
t1 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {n, m}}];
t2 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 1, {n, m}}];
t1 = NumeratorDenominator[t1];
t2 = NumeratorDenominator[t2];
t1 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t1;
t2 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t2;

t3 = (1 - x) (t1[[1]] . x^Range[0, n]) + x (t2[[1]] . x^Range[0, n]);
t4 = (1 - x) t1[[2]] . x^Range[0, m] + x t2[[2]] . x^Range[0, m];

approx[x_] = t3/t4 // Simplify;
```

===============================================

I realized that a much simpler approach is:

```
n = 3; m = 2;
t1 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {n, m}}];
t2 = PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 1, {n, m}}];
approx[x_] = (1 - x) t1 + x t2 // Simplify
```

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel Huber for this solution. but what I need to see as the output is a mathematical expression of the padé approximate I don't know too much in Mathematica but could this give as the mathematical expression of the padé approximate ?

Comment: A Pade approximant is a rational function. My answer is actually a rational function in disguise. The reason is that for simplicity I used "Interpolation" with order=1. This returns an "InterpolatingFunction" object, that is nothing else than a linear function. If you need it, I will make an add to my answer and write the interpolation explicitly.

Comment: yes I really need this, could you please add this to your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: just another question when you take t1 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t1;
t2 = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ t2; What I dont understand that you extract the coefficient of a fraction  or I am mistaken ?

Comment: Look at my answer, I added the explicit interpolation. Further, t1 and t2 are lists containing the numerator and denominator at x=0 and x=1 of the rational approximant. I then extract the coefficients of the numerator and denominator polynomials.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel Huber

Comment: Hello Zak, I just realized that a much simpler and more efficient approach is possible. I added it at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is meant by a two-point Padé approximant.  I'm not familiar with multipoint Padé approximants, and there seem to be a variety of types.  One definition is that the series expansion of the rational approximant should agree with the series of expansion of the function to be approximated at each point to individually specified orders.  This seems a good definition (or at least an easy definition) and it produces a remarkably good approximant in the case at hand.

```
nn = 3; mm = 2; (* degrees of num., den. resp. *)
obj[x_] = Sum[a[n] x^n, {n, 0, nn}]/(1 + Sum[b[n] x^n, {n, 1, mm}]);

aa = 2; bb = 2; (* orders of approx. at 0, 1 resp. *)
TrueQ[aa + bb + 2 == mm + nn + 1] (* check on degrees *)
coeffs = Solve[Thread /@ {
      CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ (
        Series[obj[x], {x, 0, aa}] == Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, aa}]
        ),
      CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ (
        Series[obj[x], {x, 1, bb}] == Series[Exp[x], {x, 1, bb}]
        )} // Flatten];
pa[x_] = obj[x] /. First@coeffs
```

[image]

```
Plot[pa[x] - Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@Michael E2 for this really nice approximation. could you modify your code in order that can work for any function? I have tried to do for example f[x_]:=Cos[x]. but in this line Series[obj[x], {x, 0, aa}] == Series[f[x], {x, 0, aa}]  My Code don't work

Comment: @user745750 I wonder what you did, because if I replace all `Exp` instances (there are three, including the `Plot`), it works: [Mathematica output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzAn.png) -- Maybe you need a `ClearAll[f];` before the definition of `f`.  Sometimes previous definitions are causing trouble.

Comment: @user745750 If you could post your input and output (in an image like I did), I might know how to fix it. You might need list the coefficient in `Solve[..., {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b[1], b[2]}]`.  What version do you have?

Comment: @ Michael E2    I will post it as an answer because i don't know how to post it like you. I have version 11.3  many thanks